# Has Anyone Built a Lazy Monad in F#?

Tags: f#, monads, lazy-evaluation

I've been reading Chris Okasaki's [Purely Functional Data Structures](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/theses/okasaki.pdf), and am wondering if there is a nice way to build lazy algorithms with F# inside of a monad that enables lazy computation (a Lazy monad). Chris used a custom extension for suspension / force syntax in SML, but I'd like to think that we could instead just use a simple monad in F#. Manual use of lazy and force in F# seems pretty cluttery.

I found [this](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-40/mail-archive/msg00059.html) implementation in Scheme, but I don't know how applicable it would be.

From my cursory knowledge and research, it seems both feasible and desirable within reasonable limitations.

Please let me know :)

Comment: This seems relevant: http://www.paul-abraham.com/MonadsInFSharp.doc

Comment: Good link @Robert Harvey

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To port Okasaki code, why not just go with F# `lazy` keyword and some helper syntax to express forcing, for example:

```
let (!) (x: Lazy<'T>) : 'T = x.Value
```

Since F# type system cannot properly express monads, I assume you suggest defining a computation expression for lazy computations. I guess one can do that, but how would that help exactly?

```
type LazyBuilder =
    | Lazy

    member this.Return(x: 'T) : Lazy<'T> =
        Lazy.CreateFromValue(x)

    member this.Bind(x: Lazy<'T1>, f: 'T1 -> Lazy<'T2>) : Lazy<'T2> =
        lazy (f x.Value).Value

let test () =
    let v =
        Lazy {
            let! x = lazy 1
            let! y = lazy 2
            return x + y
        }
    v.Value


let (!) (x: Lazy<'T>) : 'T = x.Value

let test2 () =
    let v =
        lazy
            let x = lazy 1
            let y = lazy 2
            !x + !y
    !v
```

Comment: Yes, I meant 'computation builder' :) Maybe it's not useful, but I do like the fact that the algorithm using 'return' doesn't require explicit forcing. I'd also like to have automatic forcing for recursive destructuring in the c-expression, such as let! (_, (z : zs)) = xys where z : zs are from a lazy stream. However I don't know if this is feasible.

Comment: Also, I guess I like the demarcation of when F# is in 'lazy evaluation' mode. And finally, I am still an FP noob so my tastes / desires may not make sense :)

Comment: for what it's worth, I don't think (!) makes a very good alias for working with lazy values, as it is already associated with ref cells. However, I think the over-all approach is good... maybe using (!!) instead?

Comment: pblasucci, indeed, you can choose any `!x` operator. I actually do routinely locally overload `!` in code though - for brevity. Bryan, such destructuring is probably feasible by adding another overload to the Bind method of the builder.

Comment: tpyvo, sorry I'm a bit clueless on that. Could you show me how to add that type of overload?

Comment: Bryan, sorry for the confusion in terms. I just meant a local definition `let (!) = ..`, like in the code above. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this helps, but you can avoid using the `lazy` keyword altogether if you particularly want to for some reason:

```
type ('a, 'b) lazyT = Lz of 'a * ('a -> 'b)

let force (Lz (a, e)) = e a
let pack x = Lz(x, (fun i -> i))

type MyLazyBuilder =
  | Mylazy
  member this.Bind(x, f) =
      match x with
       | Lz(xa, xe) -> 
             Lz(xa, fun x -> force (f (xe x)))
  member this.Return(x) = pack x

let sth =
    Mylazy {
        let! x = pack 12
        let! y = pack (x + 1)
        return y * x
    }
let res = force sth
```

(absent the part where force only evaluates it once).

Late, but thought it was worth suggesting.